# CentOS: which font to use for Big5-encoded files?

Tags: centos, encoding, font

This could be a very basic question, still... Which font do I need installed on my CentOS VM to display Big5-encoded files properly in the output of regular Unix commands like 'more', 'cat', etc. ?

And how can I check whether it is already installed - is it fc-list ?

Thanks!
Marina

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - found all info on this page:
https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/International_Language_Support_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_International_Language_Support_Guide-Installing_and_supporting_languages.html

Sorry for the trouble,
Marina